# Presenting a UIViewController when application occurs crash in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my application i have a login view controller where a popover is shown with textfields for username and password. I am trying to switch between two apps and pass data.

- Say this two apps are `APP1` and `APP2`  and then there are these two other viewcontrollers `A1` and `B1` in `APP1`. He switching from both apps are working fine and the data is also getting passed.
- I am trying to switch from `A1` and `B1` to `APP2` and when we switch back from `APP2` to `APP1` it comes at ViewController `A1` or `B1` depending on which viewcontroller it was invoked from.
- The problem is `APP2` is a heavy application and consumes alot of memory for which ios sometimes kills `APP1` and when i switch back it takes me to login screen. `APP2` is completely optimized with regards to memory management (it includes mostly images).
- What i want to achieve is, even if `APP1` crashes, i want to bypass the login screen and take the user to `A1` or `B1` when switched back from `APP2`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? It is an `iOS 7` application.

Thank you.

Comment: The app isn't crashing. It is being terminated (and this is normal) by the OS to free up resources for other apps.

Comment: You cannot control whether APP1 gets terminated by the OS. You will need to save the controller state in APP1 yourself, so you can restore the controller if APP1 must restart after APP2 passes control back to APP1.

Comment: yes, i cannot control when the app gets terminated but atleast i can control which viewcontroller gets invoked when the app restarts. am i right? If yes then how do i do it.

Comment: also note that i wont be uploading this app on App Store, so any hacks also would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `application:shouldSaveApplicationState:` and `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:` in the delegate.

This will save `UICollectionView`, `UIImageView`, `UIScrollView`, `UITableView`, `UITextField`,`UITextView`, `UIWebView`.

For everything else, use `applicationWillResignActive` to write code for saving state and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for retrieving the state.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH11-SW10).